# Flask-SQLAlchemy set relationship default value

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I have an app making by Flask and for database management I using Flask-admin and Flask-SQLAlchemy.
And in my app there has three role, which is:

1. **admin**,
2. **school**
3. **parent**

here is the snipet of code on my table:

```
roles_users = db.Table(
    'roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(255))
        roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                                backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

class School(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class Parent(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    school_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('school.id'))
```

The code already works fine.

- **admin** can make the school account and set the role for the user to **school**.
- and a user that has a **school** role can make parents account.

I can set the role for all of the users manually with Flask-admin interface, I can make it with a user that has **admin** role.

But, for the user that has **school** role, I don't give access to set the role like **admin** does.

What I want is when the user that has **school** role make an account, it automatically set the role to **parent**.

In my ModelView, I try to insert it with this code:

```
class ParentModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created:
            model.school_id = current_user.id
            model.roles = 'parent'
```

and then I got this error:

```
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: str is not list-like
```

and then I try to wraping it with list:

```
   def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created:
            model.school_id = current_user.id
            model.roles = ['parent']
```

then the error be like this:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

And when I try to set the default value on my relationship column :

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
            id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            name = db.Column(db.String(255))
            roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                     backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'),
                     default='parent') # or default=3 (which is '3' is the parent id in roles_user association table.
```

and then I got this error:

```
TypeError: relationship() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

So, the point what I want is to set a default value on my relationship column that defines roles users.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are trying to assign the string 'parent' when you should be assigning a list of `Role` instances.

In your `on_model_change` method you need to fetch the role that has name 'Parent' from the database and then assign it to the roles relationship as a list.

**Example** (untested)

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    if is_created:
        #  find the role with name 'Parent'
        _parent_role = Role.query.filter(Role.name == 'Parent').first()
        if _parent_role:
            model.school_id = current_user.id
            model.roles = [_parent_role]
```

Comment: Thanks, you really saved my time again :)